# html string with unicode utf-8 not getting printed to PDF file using Response object in C#

Tags: c#, unicode, utf-8, httpresponse, html-to-pdf

I have an HTML form which accepts data from the users. The user can be anyone from the world and so want the UTF-8 support so that users can enter data in any language - Arabic, Chinese, Japanese, etc.

Currently, am entering data in Chinese language and when exporting the data to PDF, its not showing the Chinese language. But, in case of English, the PDF is showing all correctly.

Am using SautinSoft.PdfMetamorphosis, its a 3rd part tool to generate PDF output.

```
SautinSoft.PdfMetamorphosis oPdf = new SautinSoft.PdfMetamorphosis();
            oPdf.PageStyle.PageSize.A4();
            oPdf.PdfOptions.PdfVersion = SautinSoft.PdfMetamorphosis.CPdfOptions.ePdfVersion.PDF_A;

            //oPdf.UnicodeOptions.DetectFontsDirectory = SautinSoft.PdfMetamorphosis.CUnicodeOptions.eUnicodeDetectFontsDirectory.Custom;
            oPdf.TextStyle.FontFace.Custom("Arial Unicode MS");
            //oPdf.TextStyle.FontSize = 20;
            
            byte[] bBytes = oPdf.HtmlToPdfConvertStringToByte(OutputAsTable(fUserAdmin, pTranslation, pReplace, pCustom));
            oPdf = null;

            if (pCustom)
            {
                var oCustom = new Custom();
                oCustom.DropTable("VW_TR_TBL_Custom_" + fCompanyID + "_" + fEmployeeID);
            }

            var Response = HttpContext.Current.Response;

            Response.Clear();
            Response.ClearHeaders();
            Response.ClearContent();
            //Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.ContentType = "text/html";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fFormName + ".pdf");
            //Response.Charset = "utf-8";
            //Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            Response.BinaryWrite(bBytes);
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
```

The commented lines above also I tried but its not working at all.

Comment: You would probably like to remove your license serial number from the question

Answer (score 0):

So, all was good with the code.

As I found, Arabic language was working fine but Chinese, Japanese, Korean languages were not supporting and its due to the PDF Metamorphosis version.

Needed to upgrade the version and it worked.

Thanks All.